# How to create table in footer with content from database

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, footer

Trying to create stationary for pdf generated invoices, I tried to use different techniques from the book iText in Action. But what I need doesn't seem to be in the book. In my case, the text in each cell are not literals as in the example I send, but need to be read from a database. 
It's not a good idea to put the code for reading from database in these onEndPage method. If I have to do this in the caller method, how will the data being tranferred tot MyPageEventListener? In other words: how can I put it all together?

```
public class MyPageEventListener extends PdfPageEventHelper {
  . . .
  @Override
  public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
     //code skeleton to write page header
     PdfPTable tbl = new PdfPTable(3);
     tbl.addCell("1st cell");  //companyname
     tbl.addCell("2nd cell");  //address
     tbl.addCell("3rd cell");  //city
     tbl.addCell("4st cell");  //bankaccount
     tbl.addCell("5nd cell");  //swiftcode
     tbl.addCell("6rd cell");  //vat number
     float x = document.leftMargin();
     float hei = header.getTotalHeight(); //altezza dell'intestazione
     //align bottom between page edge and page margin
     float y = c_document.top() + hei;

     //write the table
     tbl.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, x, y, writer.getDirectContent());
  }    
}
```

I didn't find the answer anywhere else yet, so please every help will be highly appreciated.
Lourens.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the book, so allow me to answer.

You should have something like this:

```
public class MyData {
    private String companyName;
    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }
}

public class MyPageEventListener extends PdfPageEventHelper {
  private MyData myData;
  public setMyData(MyData myData) {
    this.myData = myData;
  }

  ....

  @Override
  public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
     //code skeleton to write page header
     PdfPTable tbl = new PdfPTable(3);
     tbl.addCell(myData.getCompanyName());  //companyname
     tbl.addCell(myData.getAddress());  //address
     tbl.addCell(myData.getCity());  //city
     ...
     float x = document.leftMargin();
     float hei = header.getTotalHeight(); //altezza dell'intestazione
     //align bottom between page edge and page margin
     float y = c_document.top() + hei;

     //write the table
     tbl.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, x, y, writer.getDirectContent());
  }    
}
```

Now, whenever you want to change the footer info, you do so from the class that creates your PDF. This is shown in the [MovieCountries1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104) example in the book you refer to. In that example, the header is the name of a country taken from the database. Instead of a `setMyData()` method, I used a `setHeader()` method to change the content of the header.

Being the original developer of iText and the author of the book "iText in Action", I value your feedback. Please take some time to fill out [our survey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/iText-community).